# Is it right to say 'can you go to work instead of me?'

Tags: word-choice

I'm working as a waiter in a restaurant and I can't go to work for a few days. So I wanted to ask my friend to go to work instead of me.

Is there any expression to ask this to my friend and to tell my boss?

I got some words for this but not sure if it's right: replace, substitute, backup.

And which one can be used in an informal situation (to friend) and a formal situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think any of those three choices are particularly good in this case. Maybe *replace*, as in "Can you replace me for a few days?"

I can think of two ways to phrase it:

> 1. Can you go into work **for** me for a few days?
> 2. Can you **cover** for me for a few days?

The bolded *for* indicates that the friend will go to work on your behalf.
*Cover* is the verb I know that people use when they want to ask a friend to work for them when they're sick, have an appointment, or even when they want to sneak out (leave without permission). In my opinion, you can use either with a friend or boss.
Here's a definition of *cover* from M-W:

> [cover](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cover)
>   2 : to act as a substitute or replacement during an absence • a stand-in covering for an injured star

Comment: No problem. Please consider [waiting longer](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) before accepting an answer. It gives others a chance to post more answers and vet existing ones. :)